# React Native TextInput background color looks double layered when it's set to color with transparence

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a `TextInput` with `backgroundColor` of `'rgba(255,255,255,0.16)'` as below:

example on snack: https://snack.expo.io/rkEhXn6Nr

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.paragraph}
          value={"bleep bleep bleep bleep"}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  paragraph: {
    padding: 24,
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.16)',
  },
});
```

[image]

It looks like as if there's a view (THERE ISN'T) with that background color and a text element also with that background color wrapped inside. How can I only have the "view" to have that background color? It looks fine on android:

[image]

Comment: Show me the code. Is the background color only in View?

Comment: Without the code is hard to guess, but a work around could be adding a div with the background color that you want and make the TextInput background transparent

Comment: I have added a snack example. Also having a view wrapped around TextInput will result in odd-looking paddings.

Answer (score 9):

### Problem/Explanation:

This issue only occurs on iOS, because there it is used as performace tweak to avoid alpha blending. On iOS devices, a `<Text/>` automatically gets the same backgroundColor as the parent view. For more information about color inheritance you can have a look this [issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7964).

In your specific case, your are applying a background color to the text container and by accident also to the text itself. That's why you get an "highlighted" Text. I could easily recreate this behavior with a simple Text Component. See the following mage:

[image]

### Solution:

To overcome this issue and have a cross-platform working solution, you need to add a View which surrounds your TextInput and apply the backgroundColor (and the other container styles) there.

**Code:**

```
<View style={styles.container}>
     <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.paragraph}
          value={"bleep bleep bleep bleep"}
        />
     </View>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  textContainer: {
    margin: 24,
    padding: 24,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.16)',
  },
  paragraph: {
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

**Working Example:**

https://snack.expo.io/ByOzRyHHr

**Output:**

[image: iOS Output]

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this. Don't know if that works for you. Looked pretty decent on my iOS Simulator.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.paragraph}
          value={name}
          onChangeText={setName}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  textInputContainer: {
    marginHorizontal: 24,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.16)',
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

[https://snack.expo.io/S112z5NSr](https://snack.expo.io/rJBQgcVrH)

[image: iOS Simulator working example]